# How to change layout for the error pages configured in modules.config?

Tags: php, layout, zend-framework, zend-framework3, zf3

I´m using ZF3 and I need to change the layout of my error pages. They are called by the following configuration in Application `modules.config` file:

```
   'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
```

How can I set a specific layout for `404.phtml` and `index.phtml` pages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a specific layout for a specific action, you can use in a controller:

```
$this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/anOtherLayout');
```

If you want all the actions of your controller have the same layout, your controller can inherits `AbstractActionController` and override its `onDispatch()` method:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController 
{
    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e) 
    {
        // Call the base class onDispatch() first and grab the response
        $response = parent::onDispatch($e);        

        $this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/layout2');                
        // Return the response
        return $response;
    }
}
```

The same logic can be used in your `Module.php` where you can check if the route exists (404) and set a specific layout if not.